# Is it possible to log log ignoring data in the INSERT IGNORE INTO mysql query?

Tags: mysql

I would like to copy the data from temp_table to my table but ignoring duplicates.
I have used `INSERT IGNORE INTO $table_name SELECT * FROM $temp_table;` comand to copy.

The above works fine but I want to log the ignored data. Is it possible?

**Edit (from OP's comments):**

> I have defined unique combined with three fields like id, name, time.

Comment: What is the Primary Key / Unique key in both the tables to define duplicates ?

Comment: I have defined unique key combined with three fields like id, name, time.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if logging can be done for the ignored rows; but if you are only interested in knowing the rows which **will** get ignored; you can run the following query **before** the `INSERT IGNORE..` operation.

We will do a `JOIN` between the two tables based on the Unique Key defined, to fetch the `$temp_table` rows, which already exist in the `$table_name`:

```
SELECT tt.*
FROM table_name t
JOIN temp_table tt
  ON tt.id = t.id AND 
     tt.name = t.name AND 
     tt.time = t.time
```

Comment: Yes. We can identify the duplicates in such a way. But I would like to log entries along with the upgrade(with the single operation).